# Время задержки выполнения с переходом на другой час (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы скрипт вставал в определенный промежуток времени.
Тоесть к примеру мне нужно, чтобы цикл скрипта не выполнялся с `from_minutes` до `to_minutes` причем `from_minutes` может быть больше `to_minutes` (тоесть задержка с переходом на следующий час)

Перепробовал множество вариантов, но ни один не работает как нужно. К примеру

```py
if isinstance(sleep_from, int) and isinstance(sleep_to, int):
    year, month, day, hour, minute, *_ = datetime.now().timetuple()
    start_sleep_time = datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=sleep_from)

    end_sleep_time = datetime(
        year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=sleep_to
    ) + timedelta(hours=int(sleep_from > sleep_to))

    while start_sleep_time < datetime.now() < end_sleep_time:
        time.sleep(.5)
```

В общем нужна концепция

Comment: Что значит "не работает как нужно"?

Comment: @CrazyElf `Тоесть к примеру мне нужно, чтобы цикл скрипта не выполнялся с from_minutes до to_minutes`

Comment: А для чего такое поведение нужно? Сложно представить как и почему :)

Comment: @gil9red. Есть сайт (корпоративный хаб) кривой недоделанный и тормозной до жути с кривыми отчетами, получить прямое подключение к DB которого не представляется возможным в связи с параноидальностью безопасников. Для получения вменяемых отчетов приходится его парсить и формировать свои. Парсер работает в режиме монитора. У хаба время обновления (он и еще из одной корп БД подтягивает) каждый час. Так вот, чтобы не мешать этому инвалиду апдейтиться нужно тормознуть парсер в это время.

Comment: Стало немного понятнее, спасибо за пояснение :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну в общем схематично получилось вот так как-то.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

minutes_from = 50
minutes_to = 10

current_time = datetime(2020, 10, 5, 15, 50, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    year, month, day, hour, minute, *_ = current_time.timetuple()

    start_hour_shift = -int(minutes_from > minutes_to > minute)
    time_from = datetime(
        year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minutes_from, second=0
    ) + timedelta(hours=start_hour_shift)
    print(time_from)

    end_hour_shift = int(minutes_from > minutes_to < minute)
    time_to = datetime(
        year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minutes_to, second=0
    ) + timedelta(hours=end_hour_shift)
    print(time_to)

    while time_from <= current_time < time_to:
        print(current_time)
        current_time += timedelta(minutes=1)
```

> Буду признателен за критику

**UPD**
В рабочем варианте выглядит так:

```py
def suspend(**kwargs):
    import time
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    minutes_from = kwargs.get('minutes_from')
    minutes_to = kwargs.get('minutes_to')
    if not ((isinstance(minutes_from, int) and 0 <= minutes_from <= 59) and (
            isinstance(minutes_to, int) and 0 <= minutes_to <= 59)):
        return

    year, month, day, hour, minute, *_ = datetime.now().timetuple()

    start_hour_shift = -int(minutes_from > minutes_to > minute)
    time_from = datetime(
        year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minutes_from
    ) + timedelta(hours=start_hour_shift)

    end_hour_shift = int(minutes_from > minutes_to < minute)
    time_to = datetime(
        year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minutes_to
    ) + timedelta(hours=end_hour_shift)

    while time_from <= datetime.now() < time_to:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Насчет критики :) Лучше явно опишите параметры `suspend`, вместо `**kwargs`. Лучше не делайте ветвление и при проверке minutes_from и minutes_to сразу же выходите из функции. Лучше не импортируйте модули внутри функции, это можно использовать, но, думаю, в данном случае перенести в начало файла

Comment: @gil9red, там фишка в том что эта функция встроена в декоратор, там таких сервисов не один и не два. было бы это все не в интранете с удовольствием предоставил бы  доступ для посмотреть.

Comment: @gil9red, что касается ветвлений, то как по другому проверить сейчас тот самый период или нет не вызывая исключений, по факту `if` всего-лишь проверяет корректность значений

Comment: Про ветвления, я ошибся, имел введу `вложенности`, лишние вложенности. Т.е. проверку оставить, но сделать наоборот и делать выход из функции. Т.е. не `if ...: <много кода>` `<выход из функции>`, а `if not ...: <выход из функции>` `<много кода>`. Это сделает код более плоским и проще для восприятия, т.к. видно где код заканчивает выполнение досрочно, а где будет дальнейшее выполнение

Comment: @gil9red, вот тут пожалуй соглашусь. Ще апдейтну